# Product preview button in manage product page

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1, products-management

I want to implement product preview button on manage products page,before saving the products so admin have some idea how products are looking in frontend, there are extension available for doing this, but they all preview page after saving the products, but how we can implement before saving product?

I think to use ajax functionality to take all product fields value when call, but how we can determine what current theme and what breadcrumb will look like. If product has review and tag then display those field also and upsell and related products, default header and footer etc etc....

Comment: Might worth looking at System > Transactional Emails > Edit any template and you can see preview without saving.

Comment: Ok I'll look into this

Comment: You mean that you want to add preview button right on the product grid in Manage product or on Product Edit page to see the front end without saving all configuration, right? You can read more about this: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/31569/ I think its functions can meet you requirements! Hope that it is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is very theoretical and there is *a lot* of ways to go about it.

Its possible on EE with the Staging functionality. But we've found this fairly poor anyway.

On CE, the simplest thing you could do is just create another store view and edit the product for that scope only.

Or a programatic solution I can think is that you could make a simple extension that creates a *new* temporary product (rather than saving the existing one), then tag that temporary product with an attribute. Then you could have a cleanup cron to remove the "temporary" products.

Lots of ways to do it, just depends on what fits in your workflow.

Comment: Thanks For suggestion and that's why I had asked question on meta if this type of question is allowed or not

Answer (score 1):

An easy way I can think of is just add all the attributes as get/post parameters to a request to the product view, hook into `catalog_controller_product_view` and `$product->setData($_POST)`